# EPPlus gives unicode values in incorrect codepage in .xlsx

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unicode, epplus

I'm working on a parser that outputs the results to the .xlsx file using EPPlus. There are several hardcoded strings in Russian that I put as values to certain cells in the resulting .xlsx using the following code

```
ExcelWorksheet wsResult = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Result");
wsResult.Cells["A1"].Value = "Абонент:";
```

For some reason in the resulting .xlsx I get the text in the wrong codepage so it is shown as "ÀáîíåíòÓ" instead of "Абонент". I tried to put the Unicode codes as follows

```
wsResult.Cells["A1"].Value = "\u0410\u0431\u043e\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0442:";
```

and the result was correct. However I have quite a lot of such strings already in Russian and I would like to avoid converting them all to codes. The weird thing is that on another machine I was using for this project earlier everything was fine. However, the current setup is different so I might be missing some setting.

The current setup is:

- Windows 8.1 64bit English
- MS Visual Studio 2015 Community
- MS Office 2010 English
- all regional settings set to Russia, incl. system locale.

The setup I was using on another machine where everything was OK:

- Windows 7 32bit English
- MS Visual Studio 2008 Express
- MS Office 2010 English
- all regional settings set to Russia, incl. system locale.

I was searching for a clue for the last 48 hours with no luck, I'm not even sure whom to blame: Windows, Visual Studio, EPPlus or myself. The latter is most likely. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Here's something new. I discovered that I was still using ver 3.1.1 of EPPlus. I tried to update to the latest 4.0.4 and it worked just fine, I saw all my text in Russian! I was very quick to post this as an answer here but the very next time I tried again (without changing anything!), the problem was back. Now I'm really stuck. Any thoughts are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ÀáîíåíòÓ" is the string you get if you *encode* "Абонент" using the [Crylic encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) code page then *decode* the resulting bytes using utf-8 encoding.

This leads me to believe that in some instances your strings are being encoded using utf-8 and in other instances using Crylic and that EPPlus is always interpreting it as utf-8.

The simplest solution I can see would be to ensure that all your strings are always encoded as utf-8. If they are hard-coded that should be as simple as choosing utf-8 from the **Advanced Save Options** in the file menu:

[image]

[image: screenshot of advanced save dialogue]

If, however, you read your original string literals from another source (reading from a text file, for example) you first need to know how they are encoded from wherever you are reading them from then you can then use the [Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) class to re-encode into utf-8.

Given the symptoms you describe I suspect that all you need to do is simply choose utf-8 from the advanced save options. (I can recreate your issue precisely if I choose to save using Crylic  encoding.)

Comment: That is EXACTLY what the problem was! Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Studio and rarely use it and for some reason I didn't find anything related to encoding options anywhere when I was doing my searches on the problem. Thanks for bringing my sanity back, I already lost any hope to solve this. Thank you so much!